# remove single quote from text with python

Tags: python, text

I want to remove all of the single quotes by python in a text file.
I did this code :

```
for line in open('check.txt',"r"):
    line=line.replace("'","")
f.close()
```

but it didn't work for me.
Please suggest me a correct way.

Comment: You are opening the file in read-only mode. Have a look at [fileinput](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.FileInput) module which allows in-place file modification.

Comment: You have to write it back, of course

Comment: Use `r+` instead `r`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('C://file.txt') as filein, open('C://fout.txt','w') as fileout:
    for line in filein:
        line=line.replace("'","")
        fileout.write(line)
```